# How do I get dynamic _gets from url?

Tags: php, mysql, get

What I have is a dynamic URL. The amount of _gets will change and the values are different as well. I'm using the values of the _gets to build a mysql query, but I'm having trouble getting them out of the url.

Right now, I have this:

```
preg_match_all('/&field_\d+/', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $matches);
```

It's getting matches, I'm just not sure where to go from here, or this is even the right way to go about it. I just need it to loop through all of the **field_#**'s and return their values so I can use them in building the query.

Can someone point me in the right direction? I've been trying for a while and I'm probably over thinking it now.

Thank you

Comment: what is a **_gets** ??

Comment: It sounds like you need to use array access notation when building your query string. Something like `fields[0]=foo&fields[1]=bar&fields[2]=abc`  This way you can simply access all fields in a nice, pre-built array in `$_GET['fields']`.  Just know that anytime you see yourself in code doing something like `key_#` that this is an anti-pattern and the you should probably be using an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite know what you mean, but I'm assuming you want to get values out of a query string with unknown variable names? If so, use the $_GET superglobal and loop through it.

something like this:

```
foreach($_GET as $var => $value){
    //build your query or whatever 
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, thank you very much. I knew I was over thinking it. I had way more code than needed. So I went with this: `foreach($_GET as $var => $value){
    if(preg_match('/field_\d+/',$var)){
  $build_query .= ' AND '.$var.' = '.$value;
 }
}
`

Answer (score 1):

First start with an array of the columns that actually exist in your table:

```
$real_columns = array("field1", "field2", "field3");
```

Filter the $_GET superglobal so you only the subset with keys matching your columns:

```
$inputs = array_intersect_key($_GET, array_flip($real_columns));
```

Create an array of `field = ?` terms:

```
$terms = array_map(
    function($field) { return "`$field`=?"; }, 
    array_keys($inputs)
);
```

Prepare an SQL statement:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable ";
if ($terms) {
    $sql .= "WHERE " . implode(" AND ", $terms);
}

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array_values($inputs));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason for you to use this sort of approach.  You have a number of tools available to you that are much better than using some regex methodlogy.

First and foremost, wherever you are building that query string, you should probably use array access notation.  So let's say you currently have a form with fields like this:

```
<input name="field_1" ... />
<input name="field_2" ... />
...
<input name="field_n" ... />
```

You should instead do:

```
<input name="field[1]" ... />
<input name="field[2]" ... />
...
<input name="field[n]" ... />
```

When you submit the form via GET, this will make a nice array available for you in `$_GET['field']` that has as it's keys the values inside the brackets. Like this:

```
var_dump($_GET['field']);

/*
Outputs something like
Array(
    [1] => ...,
    [2] => ...,
    ...
    [n] => ...
)
*/
```

If you don't need to enforce order, you can use `[]` brackets to get a 0-indexed numerical array.

You now have all your values without any regex parsing of the string.

A second tool you should be aware of is `parse_str()`.  If you ever have occassion to actually parse a query string like you are trying to do, use this (don't use `explode()`).

```
$query_string = 'field[1]=foo&field[2]=bar...'; // some query string
$query_string_data = array();

parse_str($query_string, $query_string_data);
var_dump($query_string_data);

    /*
    Outputs something like
    Array(
        'field' => Array (
            [1] => ...,
            [2] => ...,
            ...
            [n] => ...
        )
    )
    */
```